# R - Plotting netcdf data on a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, netcdf, r-raster, netcdf4

I am working with netcdf-files which either contain data from observations or data from model outputs. Since the data is gridded, I am looking for a nice way to plot it on a map.

So far, I have used something similar to this to get it done:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(maps)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(viridis)
library(weathermetrics)
library(chron)
library(lattice)

# open NetCDF-file
ncin <- nc_open("precipitation_input.nc")

# get longitutes and latitudes 
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"longitude") 
nlon <- dim(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"latitude", verbose=F) 
nlat <- dim(lat)

# get the time variable and attributes 
tori <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time") # for time original 
nt <- dim(tori) 

# get the variable and its attributes 
rr.array <- ncvar_get(ncin,"rr") #dimensions (lon,lat,time) 

# Plot
m <- 204 # chose the day number of the year
rr.slice <- rr.array[,,m] 

mapCDFtemp <- function(lat,lon,tas) 
{
  titletext <- "Precipitation on 22nd July 2010 E-OBS"
  expand.grid(lon, lat) %>%
    
    rename(lon = Var1, lat = Var2) %>%
    mutate(lon = ifelse(lon > 180, -(360 - lon), lon),
           tas = as.vector(tas)) %>% 
    
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = tas),
               size = 0.8) + 
    borders("world", colour="black", fill=NA) + 
    lims(x = c(5, 16), y = c(46, 56)) +     
    scale_color_viridis(na.value="white", limits= c(0,100), name = "Precipitation [mm]") +    
    theme(legend.direction="vertical", legend.position="right", legend.key.width=unit(0.4,"cm"), legend.key.heigh=unit(2,"cm")) + 
    coord_quickmap() + 
    ggtitle(titletext) 
}

mapCDFtemp(lat, lon, rr.slice)
```

The resulting plot usually looks similar to this:
[image]

This is basically ok for a simple view, but it does not really look professional.

I am looking for something similar to this:
[image]

There are a few similar questions in the internet and also here on Stack Overflow. I applied many of the proposed solutions, most of them employ the `raster` and `sf` package, but the results were never what I am looking for.

Anybody here who knows how to do this?

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but I found your code to be really useful for plotting out netcdf data (particularly because the lat lons do not lend themselves readily to straightforward plotting. I'm not overly familiar with `ggplot2` but is it possible to change the color scheme of your code above?

Comment: Glad to hear that the code is useful for you. It has been a long while since I posted this question, in the meantime I found different ways of plotting netCDF data either with ```ggplot2``` or ```image.plot```. Regarding your question, you can of course change the color scheme and also pick your own colors. Just define a vector with the color names and then place it at the right spot in ```ggplot2``` or ```image.plot```.