# How can I unwrap this R function to see how netcdf4 data is being handled for plotting in ggplot2?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, netcdf

First create a reproducible dataset to show what I am working with:

```
    library(tidync)
    library(ncdf4)
    library(ncdf4.helpers)
    library(RNetCDF)
    library(easyNCDF)

#create data
vap=array(1:100, c(12,1080,2160))

#create the list
Variable <- list(Data = vap)
xyCoords <- list(x = seq(-179.8333,180,length.out=2160), y = seq(-89.91667,89.91667,length.out=1080))
Dates <- list(start = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-31"), by="months"), end=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-31"), by="days"))
#All <- list(Variable = Variable, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
All <- list(Variable = Variable,Data=vap, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)

data<-aperm(All$Data)
#----------------
# Make dimensions
#----------------
xvals<- All$xyCoords$x
yvals<- All$xyCoords$y

nx <- length(xvals)
ny <- length(yvals)

xdim2 <- ncdim_def( 'lon', 'degrees_east',longname="longitude", xvals )
ydim2 <- ncdim_def( 'lat', 'degrees_north',longname="latitude", yvals )
tdim2 <- ncdim_def( 'time', 'months since 1949-12-01 00:00:00Z',longname="time", 0:11, unlim=TRUE )
#---------
# Make var
#---------
mv <- 1.00000002004088e+20     # missing value
var_hur <- ncvar_def( 'hur', '%', list(xdim2,ydim2,tdim2), mv )

#---------------------
# Make new output file
#---------------------
output_fname <- "test.nc"
ncid_hur <- nc_create( output_fname, list(var_hur))

#-------------------------------
# Put the data in the file
#-------------------------------
ncvar_put( ncid_hur, var_hur, data, start=c(1,1,1), count=c(nx,ny,12))

nc_close( ncid_hur)

ncin<-nc_open("test.nc")

# get longitutes and latitudes 
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lon") 
nlon <- dim(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lat", verbose=F) 
nlat <- dim(lat)

# get the time variable and attributes 
tori <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time") # for time original 
nt <- dim(tori)
#get the data to plot
rr.array <- ncvar_get(ncin,"hur") #dimensions (lon,lat,time)
#just pick one timeslice
rr.slice <- rr.array[,,10]
```

I found a bit of code here ([R - Plotting netcdf data on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077724/r-plotting-netcdf-data-on-a-map)) that plots out netcdf data, but it is wrapped in a function and I want to see exactly what is happening to the lat lon data from the netcdf file. The code seems to create a df with lon,lat and the data, but when I try to do that outside of the function so I can see what is happening, it doesn't work for me. Here is the code modified from the post I mentioned:

```
mapCDFtemp <- function(lat,lon,tas) 
{
  titletext <- "Precipitation total: Spring"
  expand.grid(lon, lat) %>%
    
    rename(lon = Var1, lat = Var2) %>%
    mutate(lon = ifelse(lon > 180, -(360 - lon), lon),
           tas = as.vector(tas)) %>% 
    
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = tas),
               size = 0.8) + 
    # borders("world", colour="black", fill=TRUE) + 
    lims(x = c(-10.77119, -5.230277), y = c(51.35698, 55.43612)) +     
    scale_color_viridis(na.value="white", limits= c(0,250), name = "Precipitation [mm]") +    
    theme(legend.direction="vertical", legend.position="right", legend.key.width=unit(0.4,"cm"), legend.key.heigh=unit(2,"cm")) + 
    coord_quickmap(clip = "on") + 
    ggtitle(titletext) 
}

mapCDFtemp(lat, lon, rr.slice)
```

I tried to do what this function does (so I could save it and look at it) with:

```
gridtest<-expand.grid(lon,lat)
renametest<-rename(gridtest,lon = Var1, lat = Var2)
d<-mutate(lon,lat,rr.slice)
```

But I got this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

Ultimately, I want to unwrap this function, so I can change the colour of the plot (and other attributes) as well as figure out exactly how to plot raw data from a netcdfs. But I am not familiar with functions in `r` and I am clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: You are not using `mutate` correctly. The first argument to `mutate` should be the data frame `renametest`, (this is often not apparent because `mutate` is usually used inside a dplyr pipe). There is no need to specify `lon, lat` inside `mutate` - these columns already exist. Try `d <- mutate(renametest, tas = as.vector(rr.slice))`

Comment: That's great. I see what I was doing wrong now. Thank you for clarifying it. I would also like to change the colours of this plot in gg_plot. From the information on 'Scale_color_viridis' it seems that I need to define a color palette. I see there are some predefined palettes like 'Scale_color_viridis_d', but when I try and change it to ``scale_color_viridis_d(na.value="white", limits= c(0,250), name = "Precipitation [mm]")`` I get ``Continuous limits supplied to discrete scale.
ℹ Did you mean `limits = factor(...)` or `scale_*_continuous()`?``. I s this because the colorbar is being defined?

Comment: The `_d` in  `scale_color_viridis_d` stands for 'discrete' (i.e. for when you are coloring according to a character or factor variable). You probably want `scale_color_viridis_c`

Comment: hmm...that doesn't change anything. I'll have to look more into the documentation I think.